# Как правильно смотреть просмотры на сообщении?

Tags: telegram, aiogram, pyrogram

Я использую метод https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_messages
Но не могу нормально использовать, можно ли как-то данную задержку отловить и, допустим, выполнить asyncio.sleep(e.time).

Или возможно есть более лучшие варианты, как брать кол-во просмотров с поста в телеграмме, имея данные: chat_id, message_id

В данный момент код выглядит так (cid - chat_id, mid - message_id):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не приводите код картинкой, не удобно.